# How to suppress built modules from webpack terminal output?

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-2

When using webpack2.x to build my project , the terminal console the build log like this:

```
Hash: d09758ddb088e1f8cd3b
Version: webpack 2.2.1
Time: 9450ms
                         Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
   app.d09758ddb088e1f8cd3b.js    28.7 kB       0  [emitted]  app
vendor.d09758ddb088e1f8cd3b.js     206 kB       1  [emitted]  vendor
style.d09758ddb088e1f8cd3b.css    1.89 kB       0  [emitted]  app
             index_bundle.html  852 bytes          [emitted]
   [1] ./~/vue/dist/vue.common.js 226 kB {1} [built]
[1] ./~/vue/dist/vue.common.js 226 kB {1} [built]
   [3] ./~/vue-loader/lib/component-normalizer.js 1.12 kB {0} [built]
   [4] ./~/process/browser.js 5.3 kB {1} [built]
   [5] ./~/lodash/lodash.js 540 kB {1} [built]
   [7] ./~/axios/index.js 40 bytes {1} [built]
   [8] ./~/vue-router/dist/vue-router.common.js 56.1 kB {1} [built]
```

How can I remove messages like `./~/vue/dist/vue.common.js 226 kB {1} [built]` and get just this output:

```
Hash: d09758ddb088e1f8cd3b
Version: webpack 2.2.1
Time: 9450ms
                         Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
   app.d09758ddb088e1f8cd3b.js    28.7 kB       0  [emitted]  app
vendor.d09758ddb088e1f8cd3b.js     206 kB       1  [emitted]  vendor
style.d09758ddb088e1f8cd3b.css    1.89 kB       0  [emitted]  app
             index_bundle.html  852 bytes          [emitted]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the `--hide-modules` seems to be removed, adding the following to your webpack.config.js:

```
stats: {
    modules: false
}
```

This option is documented here: [Stats | webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/#statsmodules)

Comment: That did it for me and i am on the latest webpack ATM ` "webpack": "^5.65.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"`. Thank so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `stats` option `maxModules` and set it `0` so it won't show any module built. This option is currently undocumented. In your webpack config add:

```
stats: {
  maxModules: 0
}
```

Theoretically you should be able to use `modules: false` and `chunkModules: false` but that does not appear to work with the webpack CLI, at least it works with the `webpack-dev-middleware`.

---

The option is now documented at [Configuration - Stats](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/#stats).

Answer (score 1):

using webpack node.js API:

```js
const compiler = webpack(config);

compiler.run((err, stats) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.stack || err);
    if (err.details) console.error(err.details);
    process.exit(1);
  }

  process.stdout.write(stats.toString({
    chunks: false,
    colors: true
  }) + '\n');

  if (stats.hasErrors()) {
    process.exit(2);
  }
});
```

When using webpack CLI, you can try `--hide-modules` option.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are plenty of options how to configurate your webpack cli output. You can set up it in `stats` object in your `webbapck.config` file. Unfortunately I was not able to find the option which hides the lines you want.

See [Docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/#stats) about setting up cli output